# Exoplayer - can you call seekTo() while buffering?

Tags: android, exoplayer

I have an ExoPlayer instance, and a seekbar. When the user seeks, I'd like to use `ExoPlayer.seekTo()` to update the position of the video.

Can you call `ExoPlayer.seekTo()` as frequently as you want, and it should handle canceling previous `seekTo()` requests if they haven't finished? Or do we have to prevent ovelapping `seekTo()` calls ourselves?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Can you call ExoPlayer.seekTo() as frequently as you want, and it should handle canceling previous seekTo() requests if they haven't finished? Or do we have to prevent ovelapping seekTo() calls ourselves?

I think you could.

It will **NOT** cancel previous seek request.
In fact, there at least three threads involve in a seek process.
[image]

1. application thread: it is the thread you call ExoPlayer.seekTo().
2. internal playback thread: it is the thread to set target position & do internal settings to EXOplayer internally; as seekToInternal(), seekToPeriodPosition() and seekToPeriodPosition()... so on of class ExoPlayerImplInternal.
3. the loading thread: you can find it in load.java. When step 2 the internal playback thread has done the setting, it calls continueLoading() to have the loading thread to download target data around the seek target.

Once internal playback thread has done the handling of a seek action, it may arrange the action of **doSomeWork** which tries to see if there are decoded frames to be rendered (or skipped).
Finally, when the seek target is rendered, you can see the moment of seek target shown on display.

In short, you can press (deliver) the next seek again once previous seek action (such as ExoPlayer.seekTo()) has sent corresponding message into internalPlaybackThread's message queue. The seek actions is **serialized** and handled in order by internal playback thread.

Once internal playback thread retrieves a seek message & has handled it. The loading thread starts to load. If you download, demux & decode fast enough as well as there is a doSomeWork before the next seek, you can see the seek result.
Otherwise, the next seek will stop loading & do seek again (in this case, it looks as if the previous seek is ***canceled***).

As the result, it depends on how fast you deliver a consecutive seek action and the execution sequence internally.